# Comment rendered with MathJax overlapping text

Tags: bug, mathjax, comment

I posted a comment to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1011227/classify-mathbbz-times-mathbbz-langle2-2-rangle) thread, where I typed

> `Can you add the same multiple of $2$ to $5$ and $17$ to make them both be either $1$ or $2$.`

The output is in the image below:
[image: image of cooment]

The '$2$' seems to be squashed into the word 'of.'

I'm running an older version of Chrome (26) on openSuSE 11.4, if that helps.

**Edit:** The comment renders fine for me in Firefox.

Comment: [This comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1011227/classify-mathbbz-times-mathbbz-langle2-2-rangle#comment2067012_1011519)? I see it perfectly fine on my Arch Linux 64bit + Firefox 33.0.3

Comment: It's squashed for me too.  I'm using the latest version of Safari.

Comment: I recall Chrome and Safari using a similar package. Maybe it could have something to do with that.

Comment: In my Chrome 38 it renders correctly. Any reason to use unsupported version of the browser?

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii No *good* reason.  I have an old version of OpenSuSE, and I'd have to update to get the correct libraries to run newer Chrome versions.

Comment: Maybe it's time to move to Arch.

Comment: This is still a problem for me, sort of.  I don't see text running into each other anymore, but using Safari, sometimes space between math isn't rendered.  Can anyone do anything to fix this?